# How to set listing number of items per page and setting selected option on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I set listing number of items per page, removing/adding URL parameter and setting selected option all on click?

I'm working on a drop down for a search page which will allow users to select how many items they'd like to view per page. When the user click on an option, the parameter `&itemSize=*option value*` needs to place itself in the URL.

This part I have down just fine. The problem is if the URL already has for example `&itemSize=60` and the user chooses to go to 90 items, I need to replace the current parameter. Either replace its value or delete it all together and then replace it with a new `&itemSize=` parameter. What I'm getting right now is a doubling of parameters - `&itemSize=60&itemSize=90`

Also I can't get the `selected` option to switch since I'm not sure how to store the value of option selected.

*Note - the page is reloading each time the option is chosen. It's not done over AJAX and currently that's not an option. Cannot use a plug-in. Search results can be as high as 3000 results. I have code that I thought would work for taking care of the duplicaate parameter situation, but I have no idea how to go thru the logic for a new selected option.*

```js
function js_sort(forms, type) {
  var currentURL = window.location.href;

  if (type == 1) {

    var url = window.location.toString();
    if (url.indexOf("&rows=") > 0) {
      var clean_url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("&rows="));
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_url);
    }

    location.href = clean_url + forms.value;

  } //else if () {
    //dont mind this, this is part of a diff drop down
  //}
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <select name="pagesize" onchange="js_sort(this,1)">
    <option value="30" selected>30 Items Per Page</option>
    <option value="60" selected>60 Items Per Page</option>
    <option value="90" selected>90 Items Per Page</option>
    <option value="120" selected>120 Items Per Page</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with `window.history` if you are reloading the page using `forms.value`? Why not just resubmit the form?

Comment: as mentioned in the code, you can ignore the 'else if' - thats for something else in my code, but i needed the if to make sense. sorry if that wasnt clear. 

im using window.history to try and fix the issue im having when '&rows=' is already in the URL, this way the new URL doesn't double like in my example - '&rows=60&rows=90'

Comment: @rebel84 Yeah I noticed later, and edited your post, but hereafter please comment each part of your code that not necessary.

Comment: You only want to do this with `jquery`? I think it would be easier to do this with server side or html form

Comment: @Mr.x right now im being asked to do it by a boss. i suggested server side since json is being handled by the backend, but i lost that battle...

Comment: @rebel84 What about only `html` form?

Comment: would this work for you ? `window.location.href=  window.location.href.replace(/&itemSize=\n/,'')+"&itemSize="+forms.value;`

Comment: Thx @CME64 - that got me to a working solution.

`location.href = unescape(currentURL.replace("%26itemSize%3D\n/")`

for some reason it didnt like the & and =, so i had to switch them out

Comment: @Pedram - are you an admin? this can be closed as answered. CME64 pretty much had it right for a fix

Comment: @rebel84 added as an answer, you can close it now and it's easier for readers to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the next readers to find the solution

note: updated to a more generic form

`window.location.href= window.location.href.replace(/&*itemSize=\d*/,'')+"&itemSize="‌​+forms.value;`

Comment: this worked out great. the only thing i had to change was for the & and = - i had to use unicode